# Linux Deploy - LMMS and Audacity

Tags: linux, android

I'm using Linux Deploy on an Android phone, here are the installation and device specs:

My device is SM-G900F, LineageOS 15.1, Debian stable, XFCE, installed as folder, using XSDL, chroot container, I mounted storage folders for local and sd memory and I use pulseaudio.

The problem is as I start LMMS or Audacity, the phone reboots.

Comment: Have you checked your RAM usage? Perhaps your phone is running out of RAM, which forces it to use swap. If you also run out of swap Android will be forced to start killing apps. In short, you'll need to do more troubleshooting; That's something we can't do for you.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa AFAIK, I don't have swap, but something as simple as the Jack server will produce the same behavior.
And I also use Blender and KDENlive without problems.

Comment: Interesting. Since you're running a Debian container, when logged in try something like `journalctl -S 2019-02-09`, adjusting the date of course. Perhaps there's some useful information in the log.

Comment: I get "no journal entries"

Comment: Again, I get "no journal files were found" and "no journal entries"